# Control Access for documents uploaded by SharePoint Group A from group B

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

As per the title of the question I'm wondering if I have the following setup:

1 Site Collection
2 SharePoint Groups (A and B) that contain 1 AD Group as its Member.

Can I, within sharepoint's user permissions, restrict visiblity to documents uploaded by SharePoint Group A from SharePoint Group B ? i.e.  Store them in the same Library but Group B should not know that it exists?

1. Can this be done through SharePoint Group Permission Configuration?
2. If option 1 is not possible, can I do this through a custom control ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood you correctly. From personal experience managing document level permissions gets messy quickly!

i am guessing group A can see Group B's docs

This might not be the best solution but add an extra piece of meta data to the library.

On adding find out what the current user uploading the doc is part of secrity wise and add data to your new field stating a ,a and b or b

Have a custom display that also seeks the current users permissions level and gets all the documents that they have access to regarding that extra meta data field and display them.

in the library set the filter to be created by [me] this will stop them seeing anyone elses documents but the ones they have uploaded in the library.

If you need some more clarity then let me know. This explains a possible solution at a very high level .